# Why Camera access permission dialog not appearing in wechat application?

Tags: html, html5-video, webrtc, getusermedia, wechat

When I try to open below links very first time, chrome is asking for camera permission, where as same links when opened through wechat in app browser, no camera permission dialog is appearing. Can someone explain why? is there any way to request camera permission through js code in wechat?

https://simpl.info/getusermedia/sources/

https://github.com/muaz-khan/DetectRTC

Answer (score 0):

Chrome asks for the device permissions, the very first time a URL tries to access the media devices. Once you have approved it, Chrome whitelist's that URL and if it tries to access the devices later Chrome will not ask for the permission. If you try to open wechat in incognito mode, Chrome will ask for permission again.